# Prevent Web API method from being called

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am working on creating a Web API using ASP.NET Web API.  I'm currently stubbing out functionality on my endpoints so that I can then start developing against it.

My WebApiConfig.cs file looks like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionAPI",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
    defaults: new { action = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

In my UsersController.cs file I have these methods:

```
//Maps to /Users endpoint
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<User> GetAllUsers()
{
   //Code
}

//Maps to /Users/{id} endpoint
[HttpGet]
public User GetUser(int id)
{
   //Code
}

//Maps to /Users/{id}/Enrollments endpoint
[HttpGet, ActionName("Enrollments")]
public IEnumerable<Enrollment> GetUserEnrollments(int id)
{
   //Code
}

//Maps to /Users/{id}/Enrollments/{id}
[HttpGet, ActionName("Enrollments")]
public IEnumerable<Enrollment> GetUserEnrollment(int userid, int id)
{
   //Code
}
```

How do I prevent `/Users/GetUser` from being a valid route?

Using `[NonAction]` on `GetUser(int id)` prevents it from working completely.

**EDIT:** Here is the current output from `/Users/GetUser`

```
<Error>
    <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
    <ExceptionMessage>
        Multiple actions were found that match the request: Byui.ILearnAPI2.Business.Entities.User GetUser(Int32) on type Byui.ILearnAPI2.API.Controllers.UsersController System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String] GetUserEnrollments(Int32) on type Byui.ILearnAPI2.API.Controllers.UsersController
    </ExceptionMessage>
    <ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
    <StackTrace>
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext) at System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsyncInternal(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    </StackTrace>
</Error>
```

Comment: Your web service design's terminology isn't RESTful. Consider renaming methods to remove verbs or changing your URI routing.

Comment: @Dai The endpoints are all RESTful, there are no verbs in the endpoints.  The method names themselves are irrelevant since they will never be exposed.

Comment: @KyleC I edited the question to be clearer at the end. How do I prevent /Users/GetUser from being a valid route?

Comment: It would improve your question if you included the output from trying to call /Users/GetUser - when I ran your code, I was getting an exception due to the route /Users/GetUser matching multiple routes.  If that is the problem you are having, add that to your question. (If that IS the case, it is not that it is seeing GetUser, it is that it is matching "GetUser" to the "id" parameter on two routes.)  Best to favor the actual output over your interpretation of  the output when asking a question.

Comment: @PeteKlein The `/Users/GetUser` route should never be called.  It should return an error.  I want `/Users/123456` to run the method `GetUser(123456)`.  The `GetUser(int id)` method should never be exposed to the end user of the API.

Comment: I understand that you do not want to expose /Users/GetUser, but I think it is not exposed as you understand it.  To allow me to demonstrate that to you, please modify your question to describe what response you receive when you call /Users/GetUser.  My answer will depend on the response.

Comment: @PeteKlein I've edited the question to include the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing your post again, I think that you are not looking at the error correctly.

Because of the way you have your controller configured, there is an ambiguous route.

**Multiple actions were found that match the request:**

**GetUser(Int32)** on type Byui.ILearnAPI2.API.Controllers.UsersController

**GetUserEnrollments(Int32)** on type Byui.ILearnAPI2.API.Controllers.UsersController

GetUser and GetUserEnrollments share the same route. From what I can tell GetUser is not going to work if you pass it an int or a string or whatever, because it does not know how to resolve properly.

You can add a route config before your default to resolve the issue.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "GetUsers",
    routeTemplate: "api/users/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Users", action = "GetUser" }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

1. Comment out `GetUserEnrollments(int id)`
2. Call `/Users/GetUser` - you will get

```
  The request is invalid.
  The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of 
  non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'so14610664.Models.User 
  GetUser(Int32)' in 'so14610664.Controllers.UsersController'. An optional 
  parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an 
  optional parameter.
```

1. Now call `/User/abcdefg` - you get the same message as above.  `"The request is invalid..."`

See, it is not that `GetUser` is exposed, it is that it is trying to map anything after `/Users/` to `id` and failing, since `GetUser` and `"abcdefg"` are not valid `Int32` values; in other words: it thinks you forgot `id`.

---

**Try the [AttributeRouting](http://nuget.org/packages/AttributeRouting.WebApi/) package.**  This is a package that sits on top of both MVC routing (the routes in `App_Start/RouteConfig`) and/or Web API routing (what you are doing - the routes in `App_Start/WebApiConfig`)

With that package, you ***replace*** the route mappings in `App_Start` with ones like this in your code sample:

```
//Maps to /Users endpoint
[HttpGet, GET("/Users")]
public IEnumerable<User> GetAllUsers()
{
   //Code
}

//Maps to /Users/{id} endpoint
[HttpGet, GET("/Users/{id)"]
public User GetUser(int id)
{
   //Code
}

//Maps to /Users/{id}/Enrollments endpoint
[HttpGet, GET("/Users/{id}/Enrollments")]
public IEnumerable<Enrollment> GetUserEnrollments(int id)
{
   //Code
}

//Maps to /Users/{userid}/Enrollments/{id}
[HttpGet, GET("/Users/{userid}/Enrollments/{id}")]
public IEnumerable<Enrollment> GetUserEnrollment(int userid, int id)
{
   //Code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [IHttpRouteConstraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.routing.ihttprouteconstraint%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) to verify if {id} is an integer and specify the route constraint in your routes.

A sample can be found [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs).

Comment: A route constraint is a good idea, but it doesn't solve my problem.  I don't want `/Users/GetUser` to be valid because I don't want to expose the method names.  It'd break my hopes of having a RESTful API.

Answer (score 0):

Have `GetUsers` return a 404, that is the Restful way to handle it.

Comment: The problem is that GetUsers is a valid method.  It should return anything from `/Users/{id}`  if the ID isn't valid then yes, it should return a 404.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to validate the provided id. If there is no Id found, you could return a custom response message with whatever code you wanted.

```csh
[HttpGet]
public User GetUser(int id)
{
    if (id > 0 && validIds.Contains(id))
    {
        //Go do something fun...
    }
    else
        throw new HttpResponseException(
            new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                {
                    ReasonPhrase = String.Format("A valid id is required. {0} is most definitely not a valid id.", id);
                }


  );
```

}

Comment: That works, but I'm more interested in being able to return a complete error if someone goes to `/Users/GetUser` but still work when the user goes to `/Users/123456`